# Closest positive definite rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations

I have two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. To rotate $x$ to $y$ we can use Householder transformation i.e. $Q=I-2 \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}$ where $a=x-y$. Here $Q$ is the desired rotation matrix i.e. $Qx=y$. However, I am not sure about positive semi-definiteness of matrix $Q$. I also know, how to find closest p.d. matrix as shown in this journal ([Higham's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379588902236)).

But now, I want to know a p.d. matrix $M$ such that $\|Mx-y\|$ is minimized. Does closest p.d matrix (as discussed in above link) to $Q$ is an answer to this problem ? If not, is there is a solution to above problem ?

Comment: Householder matrices are orthogonal symmetries, not rotations; as such, they are not positive definite but indefinite (they always have eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$).

Comment: Thanks. But, is there a solution to my problem min $\| Mx-y\|$ where $M$ is p.d matrix and $x$ and $y$ are two given vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Just realized that I am actually solving a semidefinite programming problem: min $Mx-y$ st. $M \succeq 0$. Is there a standard answer to this problem.